# Excel table Page Wrap

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a calendar in Excel for staff holidays (4 persons). But when I print the calendar it will be cut (more pages printed) and when I resize it, it will be too small to read.

So i want to change this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

This is just for printing.

Any tips would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the Margins to Narrow using Page Setup
2. Go to View - Page Break Preview.
3. Adjust the Blue lines so that the page doesn't cut the edges of the months but does give you a reduced number of pages

It is probably unlikely that you will get it to print on one page without it being too small. Unless you can print on to A3 paper.